# Turn several strings of structured text into HTML table

Tags: javascript

For example I have the following text with no tags at all within the HTML page:

```
Color: red
Shape: square
Side: 1mm
```

As much rows as needed, but three is quite enough for this question. Even one would be.

In those rows I'll always have `the beginning of the text string`, `colon+space (: )` and `the end of the text string`.

How should I turn `the beginning of the text string` into `<tr><td>`, `colon+space` into `:</td><td>` and `the end of the text string` into `</td></tr>`?

---

Thanks to @Andrew Willems (the script) and @Phil (further suggestions) everything is up and running.

Comment: Can you give an actual example of the desired output?

Comment: something like this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6o2h3gve/)?

Comment: Is it really the best you could do for someone who's not in coding to just vote down his question? So, thank you. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original text here has some extra unnecessary lines before and after the text to demonstrate the need for dealing with, and the ability to deal with, extra lines.

```js
var opening = '<table id="newborn_table"><tbody>';
var closing = '</tbody></table>';
var origText = document.querySelector('#source').innerText;
var lines = origText.split('\n').filter(function(line) {
  return (line !== "");
});
var rowsText = '';
lines.forEach(function(line) {
  var parts = line.split(': ');
  rowsText +=
    '<tr><td>' +
    parts[0] +
    '</td><td>' +
    parts[1] +
    '</td></tr>'
});
document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML =
  opening + rowsText + closing;
```

```css
#newborn_table td {
  border: solid red 1px;
}
```

```html
<p>Original text:<p>
<pre id="source">

Color: red
Shape: square
Side: 1mm

</pre>
<p>Parsed table:</p>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: It is exactly what I need but, my fault, I have forgotten to mention that the whole result would reside within `$text = ' ';` PHP variable, so, no surprise I can't force your script working at my environment as `'` signs interact with each other where they shouln'd for the script to work and PHP page loads. Any way for you to develop your help further? I've tried to replace single quotes with regular ones but with no result.

Comment: @user3354912 simple; use HEREDOC / NOWDOC syntax for your `$text` variable

Comment: @Phil, it is not simple at all when you don't know how to use it! :) I'm a total noob.

Comment: @user3354912 http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

Comment: @Phil, thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you *actually* want something like...

```
<table id="newborn_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Color</td>
            <td>red</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><!-- etc --></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You should be able to map your string like so

```js
function createTable(str, id) {
    let table = document.createElement('table'),
        tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

    table.setAttribute('id', id || 'newborn_table');
    table.setAttribute('border', 1);
    table.appendChild(tbody);

    str.split('\n').forEach(row => {
        let tr = document.createElement('tr');
        row.split(': ').forEach(cell => {
            let td = document.createElement('td');
            td.textContent = cell;
            tr.appendChild(td);
        });            
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
    });
    return table;
}

var str = `Color: red
Shape: square
Side: 1mm`;

document.body.appendChild(createTable(str));
```